# Top menu CSS - having alignment and linking issues

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, inline

I am trying to make a top bar on this website above the menu that lists the contact information and the social media icons (I will take them out of the main menu nav) https://grownowsma.com/

The three issues I'm having:

1) I can't get the whole content of the secondary top bar to align right. I want them above the "Get in touch" area 
 - For this I've tried various CSS selectors using the align: right and align-contents: right; no success

2) I want the email and phone number to be vertically aligned to look better with the icons. I've tried various selectors with vertical-align: center. I read that VA only works inline, but this is inline so I'm stumped.

3) If you click on the Facebook icon it opens, but if you click on any of the other social icons they don't. I tried wrapping each social icon in a  so maybe separating them would help, but for some reason no luck. Any ideas on changing the HTML to make the links work on all four social media icons?

```html
<p style="text-align: right; font-family: 'Muli'; vertical-align: center;">
   <a href="mailto:josh@grownowsma.com">josh@grownowsma.com</a>  |  <em><a
      href="tel:(978)%20857-4349" target="_blank" rel="noopener">978-857-
   4349 </a>  |  </em><span><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Grow-Now-Social-
      Media-Agency-1275074409247860/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img
      class="alignnone wp-image-520" src="https://grownowsma.com/wp-
      content/uploads/2017/11/facebook.png" alt="" width="25" height="25" /> </a>
   </span><span><a href="https://twitter.com/grownowsma" target="_blank"
      rel="noopener"><img class="alignnone wp-image-519"
      src="https://grownowsma.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/twitter.png" alt=""
      width="25" height="25" /></a></span><span> <a
      href="https://www.instagram.com/grownowsma/" target="_blank"
      rel="noopener"> </a><a href="https://www.instagram.com/grownowsma/"
      target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img class="alignnone wp-image-521"
      src="https://grownowsma.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/instagram.png" alt=""
      width="25" height="25" /> </a></span><span><a
      href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/11331850/" target="_blank"
      rel="noopener"><img class="alignnone wp-image-518"
      src="https://grownowsma.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/linkedin.png" alt=""
      width="25" height="25" /></a></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this class `col-lg-0 middle` to `col-lg-12` , or style it with css `.row-menu-inner .col-lg-0.middle{ width: 100%; float: none;}`

Answer (score 1):

(FYI: This question is poorly written.  I know it wouldn't be easy, but you really should have included a minimal example of what you're trying to do.  It might have even helped you solve it on your own.  Either way, after taking a quick look into it, I can't just not write what I found, so here's a quick answer.)

All three issues should be correctable with just two changes.  Your horizontal alignment issue is because you have your nav set to `col-lg-0` (on the immediate first child of `.row-menu-inner`).  This isn't the correct value for a full-width nav.  Change it to `col-lg-12`.  Your other right-aligning rules will then work.  To vertically align the social icons you can add `vertical-align: middle` to your `img.alignnone` rule.

Comment: I'm not sure if my comment worked before but thank you for your feedback! I built this mostly using Visual Composer so I didn't even know I could change the col-lg-# but I'm going to try that in-line, otherwise I'll use the CSS fix from the other answer. I still can't crack the vertical alignment, I actually want the words to align with the icons. I tried to give all img.alignone icons the VA: centerl, but text stayed in place. I'll keep trying. Thanks

Comment: @Emigriff notifications of messages seems to be a little spotty right now for some reason.  I'm not seeing these notifications right away.  Either way, I checked the site and it looks like you have the horizontal alignment working.  Just to clarify, the class is `alignnone` and not `alignone` (it has two n's) and the CSS property should be `vertical-align:middle` (`center` is invalid.).  See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PSd5.png

Comment: yeah it seems to be acting weird. I SEE!!! Thanks so much. this worked perfect. Thanks so much for your help and teaching me how it works